# Scaffold ListBox multiple select in ModelAdmin Filter for DataObject with Enum

Tags: php, silverstripe, modeladmin

Currently the automatic scaffolding for search fields where there is an enum produces a drop down only allowing one selection to be made.  I'm interested in using existing filters to change this to allow multiple selections.

Given the following dataobject...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'Name'      => "Varchar(255)",
        'MyEnum'    => "Enum('Option1,Option2,Option3','Option1')"
    );  
}
```

...and the following ModelAdmin...

```
class MyModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin {
    static $mangaged_models = array(
        'MyDataObject',
    );  
    static $url_segment = 'mymodeladmin';
    static $menu_title = 'MyModelAdmin';
    static $menu_priority = 9;
}
```

...I'm looking for a module or a simple Filter of some kind to scaffold the Enum into a multiple select listbox

the multiple select listbox is defined as...

- Allows multiple selection
- After typing some characters suggestions are offered

And I'm asking for a *generic* solution - I can build a search context for each model admin but this is very frustrating.
Something like the following using either an existing filter (ExactMatchMultiFilter looks perfect but doesn't seem to actually *work*) or if there is one in a module or someone can suggest how to modify an existing filter for this that would be great.

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'Name'      => "Varchar(255)",
        'MyEnum'    => "Enum('Option1,Option2,Option3','Option1')"
    );
    public static $searchable_fields = array (
        'MyEnum'    => array('filter' => 'ExactMatchMultiFilter')
    );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you were intending that the `filter` you pass to the searchable field would change the scaffolding. I've done a bit of digging and that doesn't seem to be the case. However, if you used the [`field`](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/scaffolding/#searchable-fields) option instead, you can likely achieve what you want.

You do specifically mention [`ListboxField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-ListboxField.html) and while it does support multiple, it isn't enabled by the default constructor on the field [which is how it would be instantiated](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/source-class-DataObject.html#2262-2286).

What you want could be accomplished out-of-the-box a bit more by the 
[`CheckboxSetField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-CheckboxSetField.html). (I will admit, the UI is a bit average when used in ModelAdmin)

The resulting code could look something like this:

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {
    static $db = array(
        'Name'      => "Varchar(255)",
        'MyEnum'    => "Enum('Option1,Option2,Option3','Option1')"
    );
    public static $searchable_fields = array (
        'MyEnum'    => array('field' => 'CheckboxSetField')
    );
}
```

Unfortunately it isn't that easy, you will notice just by doing that it will come up saying "No options available" instead of a list of checkboxes. This is due to SilverStripe acting differently when we provide the `field` option that I mentioned earlier.

The workaround for such isn't great but is arguably still generic. I made an extension class of `ModelAdmin`, it looks for the `CheckboxSetField` in the search form and sets the Enum values for it.

```
class MyModelAdminExtension extends Extension {
    public function updateSearchForm($form) {

        $modelClass = $form->getController()->modelClass;

        foreach ($form->Fields() as $field) {
            if ($field->class == 'CheckboxSetField') {
                //We need to remove the "q[]" around the field name set by ModelAdmin
                $fieldName = substr($field->getName(), 2, -1);
                $dbObj = singleton($modelClass)->dbObject($fieldName);
                if ($dbObj->class == 'Enum') {
                    $enumValues = $dbObj->enumValues();
                    $field->setSource($enumValues);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is a relatively safe `ModelAdmin` extension as it specifically looks for the combination of an Enum mapped to a `CheckboxSetField` which can only happen when you manually specify it.

Having gone this far, we actually could look back at the `ListboxField`, overcome the multiple option being disabled and populate it with values (as it would suffer the same problem mentioned above). This solution will be a little less generic as we will force all `ListboxField`'s that were mapped from an Enum to be multiples but if we want a nicer solution, this is how we can get it.

```
class MyModelAdminExtension extends Extension {
    public function updateSearchForm($form) {

        $modelClass = $form->getController()->modelClass;

        foreach ($form->Fields() as $field) {
            if ($field->class == 'ListboxField') {
                //We need to remove the "q[]" around the field name set by ModelAdmin
                $fieldName = substr($field->getName(), 2, -1);
                $dbObj = singleton($modelClass)->dbObject($fieldName);
                if ($dbObj->class == 'Enum') {
                    $field->setMultiple(true);

                    $enumValues = $dbObj->enumValues();
                    $field->setSource($enumValues);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for our model...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => "Varchar(255)",
        'MyEnum' => "Enum('Option1,Option2,Option3','Option1')"
    );

    public static $searchable_fields = array (
        'MyEnum' => array('field' => 'ListboxField')
    );
}
```

You now have what you wanted - a multi-select `ListBoxField` with Enum values.

You might be asking now, why did I cover `CheckboxSetField`? Well, I think it is important to look at all possible solutions. I came to the solution I provided through trying the `CheckboxSetField` and it really was only a last minute thing where I realised with some minor modifications, I could get it working for the `ListboxField`.

---

As you raised, there is an issue for the above code handling an Enum across a `HasOne` relationship. This is due to the `ModelAdmin` extension taking the field name and treating it exclusively like a database field (via [`dbObject`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataObject.html#_dbObject)) on the model class of the form. Instead, we can detect a relationship from the dual underscores on the field name, replacing it with dot-syntax and treating that instead like a relationship (via [`relObject`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-DataObject.html#_relObject)).

Our updated `updateSearchForm` function would look like this:

```
public function updateSearchForm($form) {

    $modelClass = $form->getController()->modelClass;

    foreach ($form->Fields() as $field) {
        if ($field->class == 'ListboxField') {
            //We need to remove the "q[]" around the field name set by Model Admin
            $fieldName = substr($field->getName(), 2, -1);
            $dbObj = null;

            //Check if the field name represents a value across a relationship
            if (strpos($fieldName, '__') !== false) {
                //To use "relObject", we need dot-syntax
                $fieldName = str_replace('__', '.', $fieldName);
                $dbObj = singleton($modelClass)->relObject($fieldName);
            }
            else {
                $dbObj = singleton($modelClass)->dbObject($fieldName);
            }

            if ($dbObj != null && $dbObj->class == 'Enum') {
                $field->setMultiple(true);

                $enumValues = $dbObj->enumValues();
                $field->setSource($enumValues);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fabulous answer - because it does exactly what I asked.  The only negative is that now I've added this - I also tried the CheckboxSetField... but ListboxField only is coming out

Comment: @barry, not 100% sure what you mean. CheckboxSetField will appear if set on the DataObjects searchable fields. Did you flush the cache? (ie. ?flush=1)

Comment: I have tried both on an enum, I did flush the cache on every change (gotta love doing that) and each time it remained a ListBox

Comment: BTW found a more serious issue with this now... it doesn't seem to work with the dot notation... in other words if the searchable field is using a has one relation enum, then it will not show / use the ListBoxField :(

Comment: @Barry, interesting problem - I'll look into it and let you know what I find :)

Comment: @Barry, I've added a fix for working with an Enum across a relationship. I explain it in detail in my edited answer though basically, the code before treated all fields as if they were DB fields on the model class of the form.

Comment: That is much appreciated - for some reason it still isn't working in the code I want, but works perfectly in a fresh install... so it's debugging time!  Thanks again/